"original: error: tuple concurrently updated" postgres error while concurrently executing a plpgsql function -[ postgresSQL 14.5 ]
Hi stackoverflow community, this is my first ever question on stackoverflow, so I'd appreciate if you excuse my mistakes in presenting my question and really would appreciate any help.
I have written a plpgsql function that works as a middleware to check user permissions in my system, in which "function body" has an if-then-else block where "if" consists of a select statement that selects data from tables using joins and cast the response as 1 and 0 as integer if response = 1 then "then" block performs another select and return data as json if response = 0 then "else" block returns data as json.
plpgsql Function looks like as seen below:
create or replace function getUserData() returns json as 
$body$
    declare 
        v_belongs_to_group json;
        v_has_permission_in_group json;
    begin
        if (
            select case when exists(
                SELECT u.email , utg.id, g.group_name, g.id 
                    FROM users as u
                    inner join public.users_to_groups as utg on utg.user_id = u.id
                    inner join "groups" as g on g.id = utg.group_id 
                    where u.email='email@email.com' 
                    and g.group_name ='necessary group'
                    and g.status_id = 1
                ) then cast(1 as integer) else cast(0 as integer) end
        ) = 1 then
                select 
                    jsonb_build_object(
                        'user_id', u.id
                    )
                    from users as u 
                    inner join users_to_groups utg on utg.user_id=u.id 
                    inner join "groups" g on g.id = utg.group_id
                    inner join users_to_permissions utp on utp.user_group_id = utg.id 
                    inner join permissions p on p.id =utp.permission_id 
                    where u.email= 'email@email.com' 
                    and g.group_name = 'another Group' 
                    and p."name" = 'some permission'
                    and g.status_id = 1
                    into v_has_permission_in_group;
                return to_json(v_has_permission_in_group);
            else
                v_belongs_to_group = jsonb_build_object('v_belongs_to_group',false);
                return to_json(v_belongs_to_group);
        end if;
    commit;
end; 
$body$ 
language plpgsql;

select * from getUserData() as fruit;

This works absolutely fine when I execute 1 at a time however if I perform parallelism test and concurrency tests I randomly receive error "original: error: tuple concurrently updated"
Complete error description:
DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: tuple concurrently updated
        at Query.formatError (src\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\postgres\query.js:366:16)
        at src\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\postgres\query.js:72:18  
        at tryCatcher (src\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)  
        at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (src\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:547:31)
        at Promise._settlePromise (src\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:604:18)
        at Promise._settlePromise0 (src\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:649:10)
        at Promise._settlePromises (src\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:725:18)
        at _drainQueueStep (src\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:93:12)
        at _drainQueue (src\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:86:9) 
        at Async._drainQueues (src\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:102:5)
        at Async.drainQueues (src\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:15:14)
        at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:483:21) {
      parent: error: tuple concurrently updated
          at Parser.parseErrorMessage (src\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:287:98)
          at Parser.handlePacket (src\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:126:29)
          at Parser.parse (src\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:39:38)
          at Socket.<anonymous> (src\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:11:42)
          at Socket.emit (node:events:520:28)
          at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:559:12)
          at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:510:3)
          at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:390:5)
          at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:191:23) {
        length: 90,
        severity: 'ERROR',
        code: 'XX000',
        detail: undefined,
        hint: undefined,
        position: undefined,
        internalPosition: undefined,
        internalQuery: undefined,
        where: undefined,
        schema: undefined,
        table: undefined,
        column: undefined,
        dataType: undefined,
        constraint: undefined,
        file: 'heapam.c',
        line: '4260',
        routine: 'simple_heap_update',
        sql: 'create or replace function getUserData() returns json as \n' +
          '        $body$\n' +
          '          declare \n' +
          '            belongs_to_default_group json;\n' +
          '            has_permission_in_group json;\n' +
          '          begin\n' +
          '            if (\n' +
          '              select case when exists(\n' +
          '                SELECT u.email , utg.id, g.group_name, g.id \n' +
          '                  FROM users as u\n' +
          '                  inner join public.users_to_groups as utg on utg.user_id = u.id\n' +
          '                  inner join "groups" as g on g.id = utg.group_id \n' +
          "                  where u.email='email@email.com' \n" +
          "                  and g.group_name ='necessary group'\n" +
          '                  and g.status_id = 1 for share\n' +
          '                ) then cast(1 as integer) else cast(0 as integer) end\n' +
          '            ) = 1 then\n' +
          '                    select \n' +
          '                      jsonb_build_object(\n' +
          "                        'user_id', u.id\n" +
          '                      )\n' +
          '                      from users as u \n' +
          '                      inner join users_to_groups utg on utg.user_id=u.id \n' +
          '                      inner join "groups" g on g.id = utg.group_id\n' +
          '                      inner join users_to_permissions utp on utp.user_group_id = utg.id \n' +
          '                      inner join permissions p on p.id =utp.permission_id \n' +
          "                      where u.email= 'email@email.com' \n" +
          "                      and g.group_name ='another Group' \n" +
          `                      and p."name" = 'some permission'\n` +
          '                      and g.status_id = 1\n' +
          '                      into has_permission_in_group for share;\n' +
          '                    return to_json(has_permission_in_group);\n' +
          '                else\n' +
          "                    belongs_to_default_group = jsonb_build_object('belongs_to_default_group',false);\n" +
          '                    return to_json(belongs_to_default_group);\n' +
          '            end if;\n' +
          '            commit;\n' +
          '        end; \n' +
          '        $body$ \n' +
          '        language plpgsql;\n' +
          '        \n' +
          '        select * from getUserData() as fruit;',
        parameters: undefined
      },
      original: error: tuple concurrently updated
          at Parser.parseErrorMessage (src\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:287:98)
          at Parser.handlePacket (src\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:126:29)
          at Parser.parse (src\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:39:38)
          at Socket.<anonymous> (src\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:11:42)
          at Socket.emit (node:events:520:28)
          at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:559:12)
          at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:510:3)
          at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:390:5)
          at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:191:23) {
        length: 90,
        severity: 'ERROR',
        code: 'XX000',
        detail: undefined,
        hint: undefined,
        position: undefined,
        internalPosition: undefined,
        internalQuery: undefined,
        where: undefined,
        schema: undefined,
        table: undefined,
        column: undefined,
        dataType: undefined,
        constraint: undefined,
        file: 'heapam.c',
        line: '4260',
        routine: 'simple_heap_update',
        sql: 'create or replace function getUserData() returns json as \n' +
          '        $body$\n' +
          '          declare \n' +
          '            belongs_to_default_group json;\n' +
          '            has_permission_in_group json;\n' +
          '          begin\n' +
          '            if (\n' +
          '              select case when exists(\n' +
          '                SELECT u.email , utg.id, g.group_name, g.id \n' +
          '                  FROM users as u\n' +
          '                  inner join public.users_to_groups as utg on utg.user_id = u.id\n' +
          '                  inner join "groups" as g on g.id = utg.group_id \n' +
          "                  where u.email='email@email.com' \n" +
          "                  and g.group_name ='necessary group'\n" +
          '                  and g.status_id = 1 for share\n' +
          '                ) then cast(1 as integer) else cast(0 as integer) end\n' +
          '            ) = 1 then\n' +
          '                    select \n' +
          '                      jsonb_build_object(\n' +
          "                        'user_id', u.id\n" +
          '                      )\n' +
          '                      from users as u \n' +
          '                      inner join users_to_groups utg on utg.user_id=u.id \n' +
          '                      inner join "groups" g on g.id = utg.group_id\n' +
          '                      inner join users_to_permissions utp on utp.user_group_id = utg.id \n' +
          '                      inner join permissions p on p.id =utp.permission_id \n' +
          "                      where u.email= 'email@email.com' \n" +
          "                      and g.group_name ='another Group' \n" +
          `                      and p."name" = 'some permission'\n` +
          '                      and g.status_id = 1\n' +
          '                      into has_permission_in_group for share;\n' +
          '                    return to_json(has_permission_in_group);\n' +
          '                else\n' +
          "                    belongs_to_default_group = jsonb_build_object('belongs_to_default_group',false);\n" +
          '                    return to_json(belongs_to_default_group);\n' +
          '            end if;\n' +
          '            commit;\n' +
          '        end; \n' +
          '        $body$ \n' +
          '        language plpgsql;\n' +
          '        \n' +
          '        select * from getUserData() as fruit;',
        parameters: undefined
      },
      sql: 'create or replace function getUserData() returns json as \n' +
        '        $body$\n' +
        '          declare \n' +
        '            belongs_to_default_group json;\n' +
        '            has_permission_in_group json;\n' +
        '          begin\n' +
        '            if (\n' +
        '              select case when exists(\n' +
        '                SELECT u.email , utg.id, g.group_name, g.id \n' +
        '                  FROM users as u\n' +
        '                  inner join public.users_to_groups as utg on utg.user_id = u.id\n' +
        '                  inner join "groups" as g on g.id = utg.group_id \n' +
        "                  where u.email='email@email.com' \n" +
        "                  and g.group_name ='necessary group'\n" +
        '                  and g.status_id = 1 for share\n' +
        '                ) then cast(1 as integer) else cast(0 as integer) end\n' +
        '            ) = 1 then\n' +
        '                    select \n' +
        '                      jsonb_build_object(\n' +
        "                        'user_id', u.id\n" +
        '                      )\n' +
        '                      from users as u \n' +
        '                      inner join users_to_groups utg on utg.user_id=u.id \n' +
        '                      inner join "groups" g on g.id = utg.group_id\n' +
        '                      inner join users_to_permissions utp on utp.user_group_id = utg.id \n' +
        '                      inner join permissions p on p.id =utp.permission_id \n' +
        "                      where u.email= 'email@email.com' \n" +
        "                      and g.group_name ='another Group' \n" +
        `                      and p."name" = 'some permission'\n` +
        '                      and g.status_id = 1\n' +
        '                      into has_permission_in_group for share;\n' +
        '                    return to_json(has_permission_in_group);\n' +
        '                else\n' +
        "                    belongs_to_default_group = jsonb_build_object('belongs_to_default_group',false);\n" +
        '                    return to_json(belongs_to_default_group);\n' +
        '            end if;\n' +
        '            commit;\n' +
        '        end; \n' +
        '        $body$ \n' +
        '        language plpgsql;\n' +
        '        \n' +
        '        select * from getUserData() as fruit;',
      parameters: undefined
    }

I tried adding "commit" explicitly thinking that there maybe uncommitted-reads performed in background by this function even so, when pgsql adds "commit" by default in all of its function.
Parallelism/Concurrency tests description:
I am simulating 20vu(vistrual users) to call an API endpoint over 1 min that results in almost 350 to 400 requests.
Code and API-server description: Responding to these requests is a node server that is executing this plpgsql function within a async-await function.
const requestHandler = async(ctx) =>{
   const result = await sequelize.query('plpgsql function as described above');
   if(result)  {ctx.body=result; ctx.status = 200}
   else {ctx.status=409}
}


This function doesn't seem to be updating anything. I think your problem must lie elsewhere.

The function doesn't perform any writes to the database, so it is not the source of the exception. PostgreSQL doesn't support the READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level (it is treated the same as READ COMMITTED). Without the details of the "parallelism test" and the full exception message (including code locality details), there's not much help we can offer.

Hi @JohnH as requested I have added complete error description and API/code description also yes I am aware that my function doesn't update any records even so I received this error only when I do the parallelism test as described above, do let me know if newly added description can be of any use.

From the new details, it appears that the parallelism test is running the code to define the function instead of calling the function. Does the phrase "plpgsql function as described above" in the "Code and API-server description" block represent the full text of the function definition? If so, that is the cause of the exception.

Hi @JohnH thanks for you answer and it indeed fixed my problem by moving my function definition out of the controller of middleware that was redefining function with every API request. I fixed my problem by relocating function out of the API controller and refactoring the function definition to accept input arguments and only executing "select statement" within the controller of API.
